# error calling vc++ method error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol referenced in function _wmain

Tags: visual-studio-2010, express, visual-c++, linker

shows error calling vc++ 2010 express sp1 method of a object:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall
>   oper::ShowMyResult(void)" (?ShowMyResult@oper@@QAEHXZ) referenced in
>   function _wmain

**ooad_oops_exer.h**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
class oper {
public:
void DisplayDefault( );
void DisplayWidth( int n );
void DisplayLongs( );
 int ShowMyResult();
};
```

**ooad_oops_exer.cpp**

```
#include "ooad_oops_exer.h"
//
#ifndef SOCKET_CLIENT_CLASS
#define SOCKET_CLIENT_CLASS

const double   d1 = 1.23456789;
const long   l1 = 16;
int base = 10;

void oper::DisplayDefault( )
{
   cout << endl << "default display" << endl;
}
void oper::DisplayWidth( int n )
{
   cout << endl << "fixed width display set to " << n << ".\n";
}
void oper::DisplayLongs( )
{
   cout <<endl<<"hello";
}
int oper::ShowMyResult()
{
   DisplayWidth(15);
   DisplayDefault( );

   cout <<endl<<"ShowMyResult";
   return   0;
}
//
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ooad_oops_exer.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    oper op;
    int k = op.ShowMyResult();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

> 1> Generating Code... 1>Debug\ooad_oops_exer.obj : warning LNK4042:
>   object specified more than once; extras ignored 1>main.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall
>   oper::ShowMyResult(void)" (?ShowMyResult@oper@@QAEHXZ) referenced in
>   function _wmain 1>C:\xxx\OOAD_OOPS_PROJ\Debug\OOAD_OOPS_PROJ.exe :
>   fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals 1>

Comment: That LNK4042 warning spells trouble.  Crystal ball says that you have *two* ooad_oops_exer.obj files and one overwrites the other.  How that happened is hard to guess, probably has something to do with the .h file getting compiled as though it is a .cpp file.

Comment: getting below warning before the linker error, does it means something if i need to change/add specs. in .H file ?
"1>Debug\ooad_oops_exer.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored"
thanks for the reply,